# how to pass different item to next method instead being covered by the last one using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I recently learned scrapy. I want to add one attribute to each different item and then pass to the next method. To be specific, I want to make something like:

```
{'company_name': 'apple'}
{'company_name': 'ibm'}
```

but I currently have:

```
{'c_o_name': 'ibm'}
{'c_o_name': 'ibm'}
```

My code is below:

```
def start_requests(self):

    self.driver.get(self.home_page)
    cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
    company = ['apple','ibm']

    company_html_url = []
    company_item = CompanyItem()

    for i in company:
        self.driver.get(self.home_page)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='companyName' and @class='textbox criterion']").send_keys("",i)
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Companies").click()
        time.sleep(4)
        if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.companyResultsName')) > 0:
            company_item['c_o_name'] = i    
            company_link = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "companyResultsName")))
            company_link.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            html_source = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='profileSection']").get_attribute("outerHTML")
            f = open('%s.html'%(i), 'w')
            f.write(html_source.encode('utf-8'))
            f.close()
            company_path = 'file:///Users/cengcengruihong/Desktop/scrapy_learning/zoomtest2/' + '%s.html'%(i)
            company_html_url.append(company_path)
        else:
            print "%s company does not exist in zoominfo"%i

    if company_html_url:
        for i in company_html_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(i, cookies=cookies, callback=self.parse, meta={'item':company_item})
    else:
        print "no url in company_html_url"

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    company = response.meta['item']
    print company
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What behavior of this code do you expect exactly?